# How to Implement Factory Design Pattern for CsvProcessing based on Key

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have written a controller which is a default for MototuploadService(for Motor Upload), but I need to make one Factory Design so that
based on `parentPkId`, need to call HealUploadService, TempUploadService, PersonalUploadService etc which will have separate file processing stages.

> controller is below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/csvUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<String> csvUpload(@RequestParam String parentPkId, @RequestParam List<MultipartFile> files)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        log.info("Entered method csvUpload() of DaoController.class");
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        CompletionService<String> compService = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executor);
        List< Future<String> > futureList = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
        for (MultipartFile f : files) {
            compService.submit(new ProcessMutlipartFile(f ,parentPkId,uploadService));
            futureList.add(compService.take());
        }       
        for (Future<String> f : futureList) {
            long timeout = 0;
            System.out.println(f.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            response.add(f.get());
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        return response;
    }
```

Here is `ProcessMutlipartFile` class which extends the callable interface, with CompletionService's `compService.submit()` invoke this class, which in turn executes `call()` method, which will process a file.

```
public class ProcessMutlipartFile implements Callable<String>
{
   private MultipartFile file; 
   private String temp;
   private MotorUploadService motUploadService;
   public ProcessMutlipartFile(MultipartFile file,String temp, MotorUploadService motUploadService )
   {
       this.file=file;
       this.temp=temp;
       this.motUploadService=motUploadService;
   }

   public String call() throws Exception 
   {

    return   motUploadService.csvUpload(temp, file);
    }

}
```

Below is `MotorUploadService` class, where I'm processing uploaded CSV file, line by line and then calling `validateCsvData()` method to validate Data,
which returns ErrorObject having line number and Errors associated with it.
if csvErrorRecords is null, then error-free and proceed with saving to Db.
else save errorList to Db and return Upload Failure.

```
@Component
public class MotorUploadService {

@Value("${external.resource.folder}")
     String resourceFolder;

    public String csvUpload(String parentPkId, MultipartFile file) {

    String OUT_PATH = resourceFolder;

    try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss"); 
            String filename = file.getOriginalFilename().split(".")[0] + df.format(new Date()) + file.getOriginalFilename().split(".")[1];
            Path  path = Paths.get(OUT_PATH,fileName)
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed to Upload File...try Again";
        }
        List<TxnMpMotSlaveRaw> txnMpMotSlvRawlist = new ArrayList<TxnMpMotSlaveRaw>();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            int header = 0;
            int lineNum = 1;
            TxnMpSlaveErrorNew txnMpSlaveErrorNew = new TxnMpSlaveErrorNew();
            List<CSVErrorRecords> errList = new ArrayList<CSVErrorRecords>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // TO SKIP HEADER
                if (header == 0) {
                    header++;
                    continue;
                }
                lineNum++;
                header++;
                // Use Comma As Separator
                String[] csvDataSet = line.split(",");

                CSVErrorRecords csvErrorRecords = validateCsvData(lineNum, csvDataSet);
                System.out.println("Errors from csvErrorRecords is " + csvErrorRecords);

                if (csvErrorRecords.equals(null) || csvErrorRecords.getRecordNo() == 0) {
                    //Function to Save to Db

                } else {
                    // add to errList
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (txnMpSlaveErrorNew.getErrRecord().size() == 0) {
                //save all
                return "Successfully Uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename();   
            } 
            else {
                // save the error in db;
                return "Failure as it contains Faulty Information" + file.getOriginalFilename();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "Failure Uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename();
        }

    }

    private TxnMpMotSlaveRaw saveCsvData(String[] csvDataSet, String parentPkId) {
        /*
            Mapping csvDataSet to PoJo
            returning Mapped Pojo;
        */
    }

    private CSVErrorRecords validateCsvData(int lineNum, String[] csvDataSet) {
        /*
        Logic for Validation goes here
        */
    }

}
```

How to make it as a factory design pattern from `controller`,
so that if

```
 parentPkId='Motor' call MotorUploadService,
    parentPkId='Heal' call HealUploadService
```

I'm not so aware of the Factory Design pattern, please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question, in essence you would create an interface, and then return a specific implementation based upon the desired type.

So

```
public interface UploadService {
  void csvUpload(String temp, MultipartFile file) throws IOException;
}
```

The particular implementations

```
public class MotorUploadService implements UploadService
{
  public void csvUpload(String temp, MultipartFile file) {
    ...
  }
}

public class HealUploadService implements UploadService
{
  public void csvUpload(String temp, MultipartFile file) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then a factory

```
public class UploadServiceFactory {
  public UploadService getService(String type) {
    if ("Motor".equals(type)) {
      return new MotorUploadService();
    }
    else if ("Heal".equals(type)) {
      return new HealUploadService();
    }
  }
}
```

The factory might cache the particular implementations. One can also use an abstract class rather than an interface if appropriate.

I think you currently have a class `UploadService` but that is really the `MotorUploadService` if I followed your code, so I would rename it to be specific.

Then in the controller, presumably having used injection for the UploadServiceFactory

```
...
for (MultipartFile f : files) {
  UploadService uploadSrvc = uploadServiceFactory.getService(parentPkId);
  compService.submit(new ProcessMutlipartFile(f ,parentPkId,uploadService));
  futureList.add(compService.take());
}
```

So with some additional reading in your classes:

```
public class ProcessMutlipartFile implements Callable<String>
{
   private MultipartFile file; 
   private String temp;
   private UploadService uploadService;

   // change to take the interface UploadService
   public ProcessMutlipartFile(MultipartFile file,String temp, UploadService uploadService )
   {
       this.file=file;
       this.temp=temp;
       this.uploadService=uploadService;
   }

   public String call() throws Exception 
   {
     return   uploadService.csvUpload(temp, file);
   }
}
```